# Should I be reporting bitcoin losses if I did not receive 1099 for it?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, cryptocurrency, losses

I did not receive a 1099K from Coinbase. Should I report capital losses?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you'll file [Schedule D](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040sd.pdf) showing your capital gain/loss and provide the trade details on [Form 8949](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8949.pdf). The [1099-K](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/understanding-your-1099-k) is only required to be furnished if certain conditions are met ($20,000 in payments and at least 200 transactions), it's primarily for the IRS to make sure retailers report their sales accurately, not really related to capital gains but Coinbase does issue them because they are acting as a third-party payment processor.